# Hive and PySpark effiency - many jobs or one job?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a question on the inner workings of Spark.

If I define a dataframe from a Hive table e.g. df1 = spark_session.table('db.table'); is that table read just once?

What I mean is, if I created 4 or 5 new dataframes from df1 and output them all to separate files, is that more efficient than running them all as different spark files?

Is this more efficient than the below diagram? Does it result in less load on Hive because we read the data once, or is that now how it works?

[image]

Than this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I define a dataframe from a Hive table e.g. df1 = spark_session.table('db.table'); is that table read just once?

- You need to cache() the `df1 = spark_session.table('db.table').cache()` then spark will read the table once and caches the data when action is performed.
- If you output df1 to `4 or 5` different files also spark only read the data from hive table once as we already cached the data.

---

Is this more efficient than the below diagram? Does it result in less load on Hive because we read the data once, or is that now how it works?

- Yes in your **first diagram** we are keeping less load on `hive` as we are reading data once.
- In your **second diagram** if we write separate spark jobs for each file that means we are reading hive table in each job.